# passing function to function generate infinite type

Tags: haskell

I make a mistack and wrote a function like this:

```
Prelude> doWork f x = f f x
```

and I've got a compiler error:

```
<interactive>:3:16: error:
    • Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type:
        t ~ t -> t1 -> t2
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘f’
      In the expression: f f x
      In an equation for ‘doWork’: doWork f x = f f x
    • Relevant bindings include
        x :: t1 (bound at <interactive>:3:10)
        f :: t -> t1 -> t2 (bound at <interactive>:3:8)
        doWork :: (t -> t1 -> t2) -> t1 -> t2 (bound at <interactive>:3:1)
```

I want to know, why apply `f` to argument `f` generate a infinite type? Is it like a recursion?

The correct code would be:

```
Prelude> doWork f x = f (f x)
```

Please attention, that I am just starting learning haskell and explain me as I am a dummy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
doWork f x = f f x
```

`doWork` takes two arguments, `f` and `x`.

```
f f x
```

We call `f` with two arguments, so `f` must be a function.

```
f :: a -> b -> c
```

Now, what are `a`, `b` and `c`? Well, `c` is whatever the result type of the whole thing is. `b` is the type of `x`. And `a` is... the type of `f` itself. But that means that `a == a -> b -> c`. If you replace `a` with `a -> b -> c`, you get

```
f :: (a -> b -> c) -> b -> c
```

But that still has `a` in it. If we replace again, we get

```
f :: ((a -> b -> c) -> b -> c) -> b -> c
f :: (((a -> b -> c) -> b -> c) -> b -> c) -> b -> c
```

and so on, forever. The trouble is, `a == a -> b -> c` defines `a` as a type that mentions itself - an infinite type loop. And that's not allowed.

---

If, on the other hand, we have

```
f (f x)
```

then `f` is a 1-argument function

```
f :: a -> b
```

Since the output of the inner-`f` is passed as input to the outer-`f`, both types must be identical: `a == b`

```
f :: b -> b
```

And that's a perfectly sensible type. So there's no problem here.

Comment: First thanks so much for the awesome explanation. The first with infinite type I've got it but the second I do not understand. Can you please expand like the first?

Comment: We do `f x`. So `f` is called with `x` as input. So `f` must be a function, who's input type matches the type of `x` (whatever that is). Now we do `f (f x)`, so whatever the output type of `f x` is, it must match the input type of `f`. Hence, input and output types as the same.

Comment: Thanks so much @MathematicalOrchid for your help.